# WCF and Telerik.OpenAccess

Tags: wcf, telerik

For some reason when I am trying to add a webservice (custom) to a site that has a reference to Telerik.OpenAccess and try to reuse the classes in my custom webservice 1) I cannot consume the webservice, unless I remove this reference 2) when I am able to reuse the classes then add the Telerik.OpenAccess reference back in nothing in the webservcie will serialize because of this reference, the web service does work on other sites without the Telerik.OpenAccess reference.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I only include the libraries needed for the WCF service all is good, not the best solution but at least it works.  For the long term I see this as a bad solution and don't think a reference in my project should affect any Service Reference unless that reference was included in the Service Reference itself.